# Python Telethon (Telegram) keeps erroring out with "too many requests"

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

I am lookign for some advice on the Telethon python library which gave me some pain lately. This is could be a commercial opportunity, so if you are vary experienced particularly in Telethon, please do not hesitate to get in touch.

So, the code I wrote worked fine at first. I used several tg accounts (numbers) to message users and had a large time delay between each two messages. However, a few days ago I started getting "too many requests" error after several weeks of successful operation (I had to replace some phone numbers along the way but nothing dramatic). And, this error didn't go away since. I tried using VPN to avoid my old IP, I tried creating new API credentials from a different phone number and/or different IP address, I tried creating brand new tg accounts. Nothing worked. Even the brand new accounts are shut off as "too many requests" and get banned immediately after. I tried recreating and running the whole process on a different person's machine to make sure I took everything into account. No progress.

So, does anyone know if telegram has simply dropped telethon access for messaging or am I missing something really important here. Thanks! Your help will be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Send messages in a telegram to an unknown user - the limit is 50 messages per day.
When the limit exceeds, it will throw a "Too many requests" error